# android error in in android google play billing subscription it does not return purchase data and data signature?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, subscription

I have used beta testing in google play .. I have integrated app in google play..It response as like "Payment successfull.." nut it not reply a purchase data and data signature? so can you help me here to debug friends?

Product Id:

private static final String PRO_MONTH_SKU = "zoomlee_family_y";

RSA Key:

String rsa_key = getString(R.string.rsa_key);

billingHelper = new IabHelper(this, rsa_key);

billingHelper.startSetup(this);

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d("whichfirst","resume");

    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    applySubscriptionState();
    billingApi.billingTypes(zoomleeKey, getTrialsCallback);

}


private void disposeBillingHelper() {
    if (billingHelper != null) {
        billingHelper.dispose();
    }
    billingHelper = null;
}



public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        Log.d("Loadsuccess", "success");
        isSetuped = true;
        loadPrices();
    }
}
```

billingHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, PRO_MONTH_SKU, RequestCodes.PAY_SUBS, this);

public void launchPurchaseFlow(Activity act, String sku, int requestCode, OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener listener) {
        launchPurchaseFlow(act, sku, requestCode, listener, "");
    }

public void launchPurchaseFlow(Activity act, String sku, int requestCode, OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener listener, String extraData) {
        checkSetupDone("launchPurchaseFlow");

flagStartAsync("launchPurchaseFlow");
        IabResult result;

```
    try {
```

logDebug("Constructing buy intent for " + sku);
            Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, mContext.getPackageName(), sku, ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, extraData);
            int response = getResponseCodeFromBundle(buyIntentBundle);

if (response != BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
               logError("Unable to buy item, Error response: " + getResponseDesc(response));

result = new IabResult(response, "Unable to buy item");

if (listener != null) {
        listener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);}return; }
PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable(RESPONSE_BUY_INTENT);
            logDebug("Launching buy intent for " + sku + ". Request code: " + requestCode);
            mRequestCode = requestCode;

Comment: Add code you have tried

Comment: help me here frends?

Comment: write required data to file in sd card, it will help you to find out where issue.

Comment: here is example to implement in-app purchase https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive